# how to display the date inputting the user name and the last on a form

Tags: vb.net

excuse me gan, I want to ask, how do I know the last data inputted by date and user. Please help. thanks.

application design as in the image below.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add more details to your answer and show us what you have tried so far (post the actual code). As it is, the question will surely be closed soon.

Comment: This may help you. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please rephrase and provide an example if it is possible. This don't make sense.